# Adjust Andriod phone screen brightness using orientation

Tags: android, android-orientation, screen-brightness

How can I use the phone orientation to adjust screen brightness? For example, brightness is maximum when portrait and minimum when landscape.

Comment: Can I set screen brightness on portrait then minimum when in landscape?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In your activity class use the method below :** (Checks Orientation and controls brightness)

```
 @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        // Checks the orientation of the screen
        if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
                    Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
               Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 0);
        } else if (newConfig.orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT) {
                   Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(),
               Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 100);
        }
    }
```

**Permissions:**

```
<uses-permission
      android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
      tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your fast response! What if I want automatic brightness when portrait?

Comment: I upvote but have I less than 15 reputation so it will not be displayed publicaly

Comment: Its ok. Thank you. Glad I helped.

Comment: `cResolver = getContentResolver(); Settings.System.putInt(cResolver,
                Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE,SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_AUTOMATIC);` for automatic

Comment: why Configuration, orientation and Toast red? it says cannot resolve symbol?... Sorry i am new to Android Studio and this the first time I encounter it

Comment: What do you mean? Did you import required modules?

Comment: I selected optimize import on the fly and add unambiguous imports on the fly on the auto import.

Comment: I solve the issue by invalid caches/restart, but on AndroidManifest.xml says Permission is only granted to system apps on android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"
        tools:ignore="ProtectedPermissions" />

Comment: @MarcPaulEumague You have to add `tools` namespace in the manifest root element

`<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"`

Comment: one last problem, i thought all cannot resolve symbol is okay but "context" still on red

Comment: U need to replace `context` with your context variable. If you don't know you can use `getApplicationContext()` or related methods

Comment: When I rotate the screen to landscape it exit the app but still running. I tried getApplicationContext( ) and getBaseContext( ) but same effect.

Comment: i use "this" but app still exits. also when i debug 'app' there ia error says java.lang.SecurityException: com.example.autobrightness4 was not granted  this permission: android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS.

Comment: these error also show at the start of debugging: E/ion: ioctl c0044901 failed with code -1: Invalid argument
E/GED: Failed to get GED Log Buf, err(0)